# gcc make error on hpc

Tags: linux, gcc, redhat

I want to use the hpc in our univerisity, but the gcc version of the system is too old to compile new packages that I need. So I want to install a new version gcc locally.

I downloaded the gcc-5.2.0 package and configured. When I make the files, there are some mistake, which lead to process killed. The last sentence before process killed is

> /home/$USERNAME/software/gcc-5.2.0/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/prev-gcc/xg++ -B/home/$USERNAME/software/gcc-5.2.0/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/prev-gcc/ -B/home/$USERNAME/local/gcc-5.2.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -nostdinc++ -B/home/$USERNAME/software/gcc-5.2.0/prev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs -B/home/$USERNAME/software/gcc-5.2.0/prev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/.libs  -I/home/$USERNAME/software/gcc-5.2.0/prev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu  -I/home/$USERNAME/software/gcc-5.2.0/prev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include  -I/home/$USERNAME/software/gcc-5.2.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++ -L/home/$USERNAME/software/gcc-5.2.0/prev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs -L/home/$USERNAME/software/gcc-5.2.0/prev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/.libs -c   -g -O2 -gtoggle -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../.././gcc -I../.././gcc/. -I../.././gcc/../include -I../.././gcc/../libcpp/include -I/home/$USERNAME/local/gmp-4.3.2//include -I/home/$USERNAME/local/mpfr-2.4.2/include -I/home/$USERNAME/local/mpc-1.0.1//include  -I../.././gcc/../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/../libdecnumber/bid -I../libdecnumber -I../.././gcc/../libbacktrace   -o insn-recog.o -MT insn-recog.o -MMD -MP -MF ./.deps/insn-recog.TPo insn-recog.c

and the error information is

> xg++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
>   Please submit a full bug report,
>   with preprocessed source if appropriate.
>   See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html for instructions.
>   make[3]: *** [insn-recog.o] Error 4
>   make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/$USERNAME/software/gcc-5.2.0/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc'
>   make[2]: *** [all-stage2-gcc] Error 2
>   make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/$USERNAME/software/gcc-5.2.0'
>   make[1]: *** [stage2-bubble] Error 2
>   make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/$USERNAME/software/gcc-5.2.0'
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

I have searched some question about this kind of problem, it seems that this is caused by not enough memory. But I run on a hpc with more than 20G memory free. So I don't what the problem is and how to solve it.

The OS version is `Red Hat 4.4.7-3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact shows that it's still the memory problem. It seems that the login node doesn't use the swap memeory. I have to log into the test node to install softwares.

Answer (score 0):

An internal compiler error (ICE) means that the compiler has detected a bug in itself. It might be that you're using some unusual code construct that causes the compiler to hit this bug. In any case, the first step you should do is to test with a newer compiler, in case the bug has already been fixed, as 5.2 that you're using now is still quite old. The latest version at the time of writing this is 7.2.